# Linear bending of a mesh

Tags: transformations

I am trying to implement linear bending of a mesh by following what Alan H. Barr explained in his *Global and local deformations of solid primitives* paper ([ACM link](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=808573), [Direct Link hosted on a faculty page](http://www.cs.drexel.edu/~david/Classes/Papers/p21-barr.pdf), pag.5). The issue I have is that I don't quite understand the formulas involved:

[image: y formula]

[image: z formula]

Assuming we bend the mesh by an angle [image: theta angle], where [image: y hat] is the clamped value of y between some specified ymin and ymax. k is the bending rate expressed in [rad/m] (and thus the radius of curvature is 1/k). The axis of bending is [s, y_0, 1/k]', where s is a free parameter and y0 is the bending center.

Can somebody explain, possibly with an image, the terms in the formulas above? I guess that I should look for an angle alpha = pi/2 + theta, since cos(alpha) = -sin(theta), sin(alpha) = cos(theta), but I am not able to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: [Relevant meta discussion about paywalled links](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276/whats-the-policy-on-paywalled-links)